# Pinterest API image size

Tags: json, api, pinterest

According to several blog posts and the [development site](http://developers.pinterest.com/) the v3 API is only partially available (and hardly documented). I found the endpoint I need in [this article](http://techslides.com/using-the-pinterest-api/):
`https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/boards/{username}/{board}/pins/`
which returns pins like this one:

```
{
    "attribution": {
        "title": "Blue",
        "url": "http://500px.com/photo/8371303",
        "provider_icon_url": "http://passets-ak.pinterest.com/images/api/attrib/fivehundredpx@2x.png",
        "author_name": "Eddie Chui",
        "provider_favicon_url": "http://passets-ec.pinterest.com/images/api/attrib/fivehundredpx.png",
        "author_url": "http://500px.com/EddieChui",
        "provider_name": "fivehundredpx"
    },
    "description": "Khiva Uzbekistan",
    "pinner": {
        "image_small_url": "http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/avatars/iweczek-1349184554_30.jpg",
        "profile_url": "http://www.pinterest.com/highquality/",
        "full_name": "A B"
    },
    "dominant_color": "#434744",
    "link": "http://500px.com/photo/8371303",
    "images": {
        "237x": {
            "url": "http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/237x/b4/14/66/b414661df939392b2f0425e394be83db.jpg",
            "width": 237,
            "height": 359
        }
    },
    "is_video": false,
    "id": "159596380518659971"
}
```

According to the [domain api docs](http://developers.pinterest.com/api_docs/) there is a possibility to specify what image sizes you would like to receive by providing:
`pin.images=[64x64,75x75,1200x]`

Any idea if this is possible for the specified endpoint? If yes, how do I include it in the request?

Comment: Hi, did you get to know how to use this? I need to get paginated pins for a pinterest user and user's public info, like followers_count.
Can you help me with this if you know how to do it?
I also read somewhere that if I have an API-KEY it would be easy, but there is nowhere mentioned how to get that API-KEY, please share if you have any knowledge about this..

Comment: @SambhavSharma As far as I know it is not possible. As you said, you need an API-KEY to use the full API. The API is not public and I don't know if there are plans to make it public at any point. I tried to get a Key but didn't get a response from Pinterest. Not even when requesting it for research purposes from my faculty address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of June 2014 it is not possible to use the full Pinterest v3 API without an API-KEY. The API is not public so it is quite hard to get an API-KEY from Pinterest. To request a KEY you have to specify what kind of application you use it for, including mockups/wireframes. The form to request a key is located [here](https://developers.pinterest.com/api_request/). But there was no response from Pinterest for my requests, not even when requesting it for research purposes from a CS faculty of a well known university.

Some very basic features of the original Pinterest API have been replicated by [this API](https://www.mashape.com/novaleaf/pinterest-to-json#!documentation). But it is extremely slow because it relies on scraping the Pinterest page and I guess any changes to the DOM will break it. The support is also limited.

The mentioned API is based on [PhantomJsCloud](https://www.mashape.com/novaleaf/phantomjs-cloud-web-browser-and-webpage-processing-as-a-service#!documentation). It uses [this file](https://googledrive.com/host/0BwZ2bMDOKaeDYWYzYzgxNDYtNmQyYi00ZDk5LWE3ZTYtODQ0ZDAzNTBkY2M4/phantomjscloud-examples/pinterest-parser2.js) for the scraping so If you want to use it productively I would advise you to directly use PhantomJsCloud and modify the specified file so you can react to DOM changes of Pinterest and be able to change the API response because as I said, the support of the other API is limited.

Comment: Pinterest API in Mashape - https://www.mashape.com/ismaelc/pinterest-1#!documentation

Answer (score 4):

You can get to the larger images by using the API to get to the 237x size and then replacing it with "originals" in the url

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: "https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/boards/vicemag/magazine/pins/" ,
  success: function(data) {
    var npins = data.data.pins.length
    for (var i = 0; i < npins; i++) {
      var a = data.data.pins[i].images["237x"].url,
          a = a.replace('237x','originals')
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In asp.Net C#, I used:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(Response);
        foreach (var data in results.data.pins)
        {
              string str = Convert.ToString(data.images["237x"].url);
              str = BigImg.Replace("237x", "736x");
        }
```

It worked for me. Hope same for you.